# Allow users to combine tables without using eval

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, eval

In my app I need to allow users to do calculations such as add/subtract/divide values from rows in different tables. Is there a safer way to do this than using eval()? Is it better to take a string as an input and write my own functions to parse the string to do calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just filter out the non digits and non operands

```
var1 = "4+4;haha i'm a nasty command"
var1.gsub!(/[^\d|\+-\/\*]/,"")
p eval(var1) => 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Same reason as why you should not use user input for SQL querys directly to avoid sql injection: In this case you should not do it to avoid code injection.ii